# jinja2 accessing nested list in a dict

Tags: python, jinja2

I am currently working on making a python code generator to quickly mock up a django project.

I have a xml file that has all the model data in. From there it will go away and mock up the models, generic views, templates ect with jinja2.

I am struggling to get jinja to access nested lists inside dicts though.

code_gen.py

```
models = {}

    tree = ET.parse('models.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    for child in root:
        models[child.tag] = []
        for c in child:
            models[child.tag].append(c.tag)

    print models

    t = Template("""from django.db import models

    {% for class in model %}
    class {{ class }}(models.Model):
        {% for occurrence in occurrences %}{{ occurrence }}{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    """)

    i = t.render(model=models)

    fo = open('test.py', 'wb')
    fo.write(i)
    fo.close()
```

models.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Models>
    <Model1>
        <CharField max_length="10" null="True" blank="True">Firstname</CharField>
        <IntegerFieldnull null="True" blank="True">age</IntegerField>
    </Model1>
    <Model2>
        <EmailField max_length="10" null="True" blank="True">email</EmailField>
        <DateField null="True" blank="True">DOB</DateField>
    </Model2>
</Models>
```

If i print out models i get:

```
{'Model2': ['EmailField', 'DateField'], 'Model1': ['CharField', 'IntegerField']}
```

When i add it to the template i get the class name but none of the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using `{% for occurrence in occurrences %}`, but you have not set `occurrences` anywhere.

The easiest fix is to loop through the items of the dictionary, then you have they key (model) and value (list of fields) at the same time.

```
{% for class, occurences in model.items() %}
class {{ class }}(models.Model):
    {% for occurrence in occurrences %}{{ occurrence }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```